# untar_data from fast.ai fails to download dataset

Tags: python, fast-ai

This piece of code:

```
from fastai.vision import *
path = untar_data(URLs.CAMVID)
```

logs this to console:

```
Downloading https://s3.amazonaws.com/fast-ai-imagelocal/camvid
```

but download never really finishes. If you open this url, you get:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it is downloading in fact, but doesn't give any sign of it. The file is 500Gb of size and is located under another url: https://s3.amazonaws.com/fast-ai-imagelocal/camvid.tgz